# Python PIL Image.new - width automaticly 100% depending on Text / Brand - how to do that?

Tags: python, python-2.7, width, python-imaging-library

I am creating a branding tool and have a problem with the width. I am getting a text from a Tkinter Entry and then calculating the width by checking the length of the text (thats not so good, but works in most cases):

```
brand_text_width = len(self.brand_entry.get()) * 50
```

There must be a way to do this more dynamic. What I need is a way that the width is 100% doesnt matter what I type in. The problem can be seen in this pictures very well:

if I type 6 x W it creates a 300 width picture but not all W`s fit in.
If I type 6 x I it creates a 300 width picture but not the whole space is used.
I need in both cases the full width.
[image]

Here is the whole method which is used to create a transparent picture with a brand on it. I need to replace the brand_text_width in the Image.new with something. It feels like a simple issue but I havent found a solution yet maybe someone can help, thanks!

```
def save_image(self):
    brand_text_width = len(self.brand_entry.get()) * 50
    brand_bg = Image.new('RGBA',(brand_text_width, 110))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(brand_bg)
    fonts_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'fonts')
    font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fonts_path, 'micross.ttf'), 96)
    draw.text((0, 0),self.brand_entry.get(),(0,0,0),font=font)
    """ hier wird das Bild gespeichert, nachher kann man noch mehr filetypes hinzufuegen und quality manuel beeinflussen """
    brand_bg.save(asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png',filetypes=[('Portable Network Graphics', '.png'),('WyoLum Image Format', '.WIF')]), quality=85)
    showinfo("Information","Brand erfolgreich erstellt")
```